# Зависает машина на stress test'ах

Tags: linux, администрирование, виртуальная-машина, виртуализация

Существует некий сервер с `centos 7` и `libvirt` на борту. Создаю виртуальную машину из `cloud image centos 7`, запускаю там stress test

```
stress-ng --vm 2 --vm-bytes 2G --mmap 2 --mmap-bytes 2G --page-in
```

Через некоторое время гостевая машина зависает, последнее что есть в консоли

```
[ 8141.025772] Out of memory: Kill process 4548 (stress-ng-vm) score 1350 or sacrifice child
[ 8141.029147] Killed process 4548 (stress-ng-vm) total-vm:2141360kB, anon-rss:2324kB, file-rss:20kB, shmem-rss:1462556kB
[ 8641.172660] INFO: task kworker/2:2:4432 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ 8641.203919] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[ 8641.208179] kworker/2:2     D ffff96e778de30c0     0  4432      2 0x00000080
[ 8641.233143] Call Trace:
[ 8641.237718]  [<ffffffff8d567c49>] schedule+0x29/0x70
[ 8641.256133]  [<ffffffff8d565721>] schedule_timeout+0x221/0x2d0
[ 8641.277657]  [<ffffffff8cedc766>] ? select_task_rq_fair+0x5a6/0x760
[ 8641.280047]  [<ffffffff8d567ffd>] wait_for_completion+0xfd/0x140
[ 8641.282538]  [<ffffffff8ced67b0>] ? wake_up_state+0x20/0x20
[ 8641.293074]  [<ffffffff8cec1a8a>] kthread_create_on_node+0xaa/0x140
[ 8641.305075]  [<ffffffff8cebacc0>] ? manage_workers.isra.25+0x2a0/0x2a0
[ 8641.307629]  [<ffffffff8ceba88b>] create_worker+0xeb/0x200
[ 8641.309786]  [<ffffffff8cebab16>] manage_workers.isra.25+0xf6/0x2a0
[ 8641.312059]  [<ffffffff8cebb043>] worker_thread+0x383/0x3c0
[ 8641.314152]  [<ffffffff8cebacc0>] ? manage_workers.isra.25+0x2a0/0x2a0
[ 8641.316638]  [<ffffffff8cec1c31>] kthread+0xd1/0xe0
[ 8641.318563]  [<ffffffff8cec1b60>] ? insert_kthread_work+0x40/0x40
[ 8641.320820]  [<ffffffff8d574c37>] ret_from_fork_nospec_begin+0x21/0x21
[ 8641.323154]  [<ffffffff8cec1b60>] ? insert_kthread_work+0x40/0x40
```

С чем это может быть связано? Это я неправильно использую stress-ng и вероятность подобного в проде стремится к нулю, либо есть какая-то проблема? Как это диагностировать?